# ReactRouter v6: how to specify parent component to specific routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using ReactRouter v6 and running into a scenario where some pages require shared parent components but some others not, here is an example of my application (URL to component name):

- `/`: `<UserCenter />`
- `/dashboard`: `<Dashboard />`
- `/profile`: `<Profile />`
- `/login`: `<SignIn />`
- `/logout`: `<SignOut />`
- `*`: `<NotFoundPage />`

The former 3 pages (/, /dashboard and /profile) share multiple common parent components like sidebar, footer, title bar, etc. after a successful login, while the rest 3 (/login, /logout and not found) are full screen pages without parent dependents.

I would like to know how I can organize routes to wrap them programmatically under different parent components, and be able to access them at the same time (because I need to enable navigation, for example, auto redirect to `/` if a login user is accessing `/login` path)? Thanks!

A pseudo example to what I would like to achieve:

```html
const Routing = (
    <div>
        // Render these 3 pages in routes directly
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/login' element={<SignIn />}
            <Route path='/logout' element={<SignOut />}
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />}
        </Routes>

        // Render these 3 pages with parent components
        <Header>
            <Sidebar>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<UserCenter />}
                    <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}
                    <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />}
                </Routes>
            </Sidebar>
        </Header>
    </div>
);

const APP = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routing />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes)

> Omitting the path makes this route a "layout route". It participates in UI nesting, but it does not add any segments to the URL.

`<UserCenter/>`, `<Dashboard/>` and `<Profile/>` components will be rendered by `<Outlet>` inside `<Layout/>` component.

`<SignIn/>`, `<SignOut/>` and `<NotFound/>` component will be rendered in `<App/>` component directly.

`App.tsx`:

```
import { Outlet, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header>header</header>
            <aside>sidebar</aside>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Routes>
                <Route element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route path="/" element={<div>user center</div>} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<div>dashboard</div>} />
                    <Route path="/profile" element={<div>profile</div>} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/login" element={<div>sign in</div>} />
                <Route path="/logout" element={<div>sign out</div>} />
                <Route path="*" element={<div>not found</div>} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76896670-mv3zy5?file=/src/App.tsx)

package versions:

- `react-router-dom`: `6.10.0`
- `react`: `18.2.0`
- `react-dom`: `18.2.0`